# URL suggestions for SEO and userfriendliness

Tags: seo, friendly-url

What do you guys think is better?

```
mysite.com/<username>/media/<mediaId>/<title>
or
mysite.com/<username>/media/<title>-<mediaId>
```

The title portion is ignored entirely and only exist to provide user readable urls. It can change. What do you guys think is better? A pro for the former is if the title is cut off/not linked the url will still resolve but the pro for the latter is the left side is readable and the ugly id is on the right and may not be noticed.

I actually dont know if i'll have problems resolving the mediaId if i combine it with the title.

Do you guys suggest another type of URL? which do you think is best?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first `mysite.com/<username>/media/<mediaId>/<title>` is better, and it may help with SEO.  It's also the structure that StackOverflow itself uses.

Answer (score 1):

From the SEO perspective: **No change**

From User Friendliness perspective:

```
mysite.com/<username>/media/<title>-<mediaId>
```

But it's just my opinion

Comment: What is your reasoning behind 'No change?' As far as I have heard, intricacies of the methods used by the big search engines are fairly mysterious - one format may be preferred over another.

Comment: I like it, too. mediaId and title are both attributes of the same thing.

Comment: My reasoning is that the title is in the url in both cases, so the "weight" is the same. Of course I'm not Sergey or Larry and I can be perfectly wrong but we will never know for sure. In fact, the rules can change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've messed around on very large sites (million+ pages) with different URL structures, e.g.:

- cgi-bin with parameters and no keywords
- nested keywords (using a pseudo-folder structure '/')
- nested keywords (using a pseudo-flat structure '-')
- keyword ordering with dynamic first, and dynamic last etc

Honestly you're not going to notice anything really different in terms of SEO, as long as you do have the keyword in the URL.

In terms of usability, well that can be subjective and there's no proven order, but since most English users read LTR (left to right), then you should aim to have the keywords (title) hanging at the end otherwise it can get lost in the surrounding meta (after the domain). This approach also depends on URL length as it will get truncated in bookmarks, browser chrome, search results etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, yet I believe the second one is better. 
From the SEO perspective, ID is worse than word! That means - is better /, as put those ID in the tail of URL is better than put it close to the head!

Repeat again: My own opinion, I am not sure!